# How do I plot logistic function in R with x set as -10 to 10?

Tags: r

How would I assign multiple values to x (defined as -10 to 10), and then plot its logistic function (plot y = logistic(x) = 1/(1+exp(−x))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `plot()` as follows:

```
plot(function(x) 1/(1+exp(−x)), from = -10, to = 10)
```

The logistic function is also in the `plogis` function, so you can just run

```
plot(plogis, from = -10, to = 10)
```

Generally, computing-related questions are not appropriate for CrossValidated and should be asked on StackOverflow.